# Refactoring impl from original library `use super`

Tags: rust

I'm still learning Rust, and trying to work with `rust-cssparser` to re-use an impl defined in the source library, but getting the compile error, `cannot define inherent impl for a type outside of the crate where the type is defined`. Of course, the library uses `use super::Token;`, but I need to `use cssparser::{ Token };`, and don't know how to resolve. https://github.com/servo/rust-cssparser/blob/master/src/serializer.rs#L503-L552

excerpt:

```
impl<'a> Token<'a> {
    /// Categorize a token into a type that determines when `/**/` needs to be inserted
    /// between two tokens when serialized next to each other without whitespace in between.
    ///
    /// See the `TokenSerializationType::needs_separator_when_before` method.
    pub fn serialization_type(&self) -> TokenSerializationType {
        use self::TokenSerializationTypeVariants::*;
        TokenSerializationType(match *self {
            Token::Ident(_) => Ident,
            Token::AtKeyword(_) | Token::Hash(_) | Token::IDHash(_) => AtKeywordOrHash,
            ...
        })
    }
}
```

Based on the help, `note: define and implement a trait or new type instead` and some searching, I've tried a couple variants below, but I was getting nowhere or deeper into the weeds of compile errors. Thanks for any help.

```
use cssparser::{
    Token as Tkn,
  // Token
};

// struct Token<'a>(Tkn<'a>); // requires changing lots of refs
type Token<'a> = Tkn<'a>;
```

Comment: Please provide a full [mre] and the full error message. Note that from what you have given us, I can tell you that the issue is _not_ with the `use` statement but rather with an `impl` somewhere (possibly the `impl Token`?).

Comment: It's not obvious what you are actually trying to do. Do you want to implement a new method to an existing type? You can do that by defining your own trait that specifies the method, and implementing the trait for the `Token` type. Then using your trait will enrich all values of the `Token` type with the new method.

Comment: @user4815162342 was answer what you meant? Thanks.. trying to get perspective

Comment: Yes, that's it. And if you want to get the method on `Token` in a different module, you need to `use` your trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reimplement a type that has been declared outside your crate. This is because any functions you would add in the `impl <'a> Token<'a>` wouldn't be known to any other crates that use `Token`. By re-implementing, implementations of the same type would differ between crates and that's why it's not allowed.

**The solution**

The correct thing to do here is to declare a trait let's say `SerializationType` with the `serialization_type` function and then implement `SerializationType` for `Token`.

```
pub trait SerializationType<'a> {
    fn serialization_type(&self) -> TokenSerializationType;
}

impl<'a> SerializationType<'a> for Token<'a> {
    fn serialization_type(&self) -> TokenSerializationType {
        use self::TokenSerializationTypeVariants::*;
        TokenSerializationType(match *self {
            Token::Ident(_) => Ident,
            Token::AtKeyword(_) | Token::Hash(_) | Token::IDHash(_) => AtKeywordOrHash,
            ...
        })
    }
}
```

**Alternate solution**

An alternate solution would be to create a new type. Note that an alias type does not create a new type so it will trigger the same error.

```
pub type CustomToken<'a> = Token<'a>;
```

You should encapsulate `Token<'a>` into a struct and then implement that struct:

```
struct CustomToken<'a>(Token<'a>);

impl <'a> CustomToken<'a> {
    fn serialization_type(&self) -> TokenSerializationType {
        use self::TokenSerializationTypeVariants::*;
        TokenSerializationType(match *self {
            Token::Ident(_) => Ident,
            Token::AtKeyword(_) | Token::Hash(_) | Token::IDHash(_) => AtKeywordOrHash,
            ...
        })
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the trait-based solution is better.

Comment: I tried the alternate solution, and got mismatched type errors w/ Token. The trait solutions works and is clean.